# I'm trying to position the image card to overlay the card top border using "bootstrap", need help . or I can do it only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

I wany to position the image card to overlay the card top border using Bootstrap? without using css.

I've tried using CSS :

```
style="margin: -50px 70px;"
```

but I want to make it with bootstrap

Comment: you use positions, give `position:relative` to parent `div` and `position:absolute, top:0, left:0, right:0` to content div. and you can move the image by changing top,left, bottom or right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the following classes `position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle` which will position the middle of the element 0 from top, centered left to right. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/#center-elements

Here is an example:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-5">
      <div class="card mt-5 pt-5">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="rounded-circle w-50 position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle" alt="">
        <div class="card-body text-center pt-5">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-5">
      <div class="card mt-5 pt-5">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/199/200" class="rounded-circle w-50 position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle" alt="">
        <div class="card-body text-center pt-5">

          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-5">
      <div class="card mt-5 pt-5">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/198" class="rounded-circle w-50 position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle" alt="">
        <div class="card-body text-center pt-5">

          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-5">
      <div class="card mt-5 pt-5">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/199" class="rounded-circle w-50 position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle" alt="">
        <div class="card-body text-center pt-5">

          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the margin and padding classes on the `.col`, `.card`, and `.card-body` are needed to keep the image from overlapping other elements or going off-canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and you didn't provide any your code. so I think you can solve this problem like this way,

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
     <div class="border border-dark text-center">
          <img
            width="90"
            height="90"
            style="border-radius: 100%; margin-top: -45px"
            src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/65.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <h3>Name Here</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Necessitatibus pariatur nisi veniam dolorem architecto, 
            voluptatibus maxime eaque accusantium illum magni.
          </p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

ignore the `row` and `col-md-6 col-xl-3` class. This classes are used to give a shape like your image. simply you can solve your problem with `margin-top` css.